# PHP preg_match length 3276 limit

Tags: php, preg-match

It appears that PHP's `preg_match` has a 3276 character limit for matching repeating characters in some cases.

i.e.

`^(.|\s){0,3276}$` works, but `^(.|\s){0,3277}$` does not.

It doesn't seem to always apply, as `/^(.){0,3277}$/` works.

I can't find this mentioned anywhere in PHP's documentation or the bug tracker. The number 3276 seems a bit of an odd boundary, the only thing I can think of is that it's approximately 1/10th of 32767, which is the limit for a signed 16-bit integer.

`preg_last_error()` returns 0.

I've reproduced the issue on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ as well as my local system and the webserver.

EDIT: Looks like we're getting "Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 16" out of the code, so it appears to be the same issue as [PHP preg_match_all limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268624/php-preg-match-all-limit).

However, the regex itself isn't very large... Does PHP do some kind of expansion when you have repeating groups that's making it too large?

Comment: it's more then likely is a memory boundary, preg_match will return an array with that many elements so you need to have enough memory to allow for a large array, try bumping up your max memory limit and see if it changes.

Comment: Did you check `preg_last_error()`?

Comment: is your error reporting on? there should be some kind of error if you use too much memory

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match\_all limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268624/php-preg-match-all-limit) (I suspect that this is the error you're getting, and is simply being suppressed).

Comment: preg_last_error() returns 0, I'll add that to the post.

Comment: I guess the code in the question are just examples you've come up with to demo the problem rather than your real-world code, right? (because I can't really see why you wouldn't be starting with `strlen()` rather than regex for this example)

Comment: The regex examples are based on those provided by a client. Basically, we have a system where the user can enter their own validation regexes for form fields, they can't enter PHP code.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the upper limit, like so: ^(.|\s){0,}$

Comment: Why would anyone need a pattern like `(.|\s)`. That's "any character" or "a while space character". The latter is included in the former anyway, so the pattern is redundant. It'll still cause the parser to do loads of back-tracking though.

Comment: Oh, and just a thought re "the client can enter their own regex". Be careful not to allow them to enter the `e` modifier on the end, as that could result in them running arbitrary PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle Perl-compatible regular expressions, PHP just bundles a [third-party library](http://pcre.org/) that takes care of the job. The behaviour you describe is actually [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers):

> The "*" quantifier is equivalent to {0,} , the "+" quantifier to {1,}
>   , and the "?" quantifier to {0,1} . **n and m are limited to
>   non-negative integral values less than a preset limit defined when
>   perl is built.** This is usually 32766 on the most common platforms.

So there's always a hard limit. Why do your tests suggest that PHP limit is 10 times smaller than the typical one? No idea about that :)

Comment: +1 because this is probably the issue. The smaller limit seen in the question only applies when combining `.` and `\s` in a way that is virtually guaranteed to produce large amounts of backtracking. If we guess that the limit is affected by backtracking (which is a reasonable guess) then it would not be a surprise if the limit came down to this sort of level.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^(.|\s){0,3276}(.|\s){0,1}$`