# PHP preg match all limit 3725 characters

Tags: php, preg-match-all

how to increase search character limit? now in example is 3276 characters but in 3275 its works ok

```
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "23001337");
ini_set("pcre.recursion_limit", "23001337");

$str = "<div>";
for ($x=1;$x<=327;$x++){
    $str .= "1234567890";
}
$str .="123456";
$str .= "</div>";

$w1 = "/<div>((.*?|\n)*)<\/div>/";
preg_match_all($w1, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I think it's an unpatched PHP bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45735#1365812629

Comment: ^ or that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926195/php-preg-match-length-3276-limit

Comment: If changing http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php does not work then you will probably need to modify your regular expression to avoid triggering this limitation.

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: @revo `preg_match_all()` is failing when `$str` reaches some byte count.

Comment: That's obvious but it's not clear whether or not he is trying to find a solution or reason. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling pcre.jit (don't use PCRE's just-in-time compilation):

```
<?php
ini_set("pcre.jit", "0");

$str = "<div>";
for ($x=1;$x<=327;$x++){
    $str .= "1234567890";
}
$str .="123456";
$str .= "</div>";

$w1 = "/<div>((.*?|\n)*)<\/div>/";
preg_match_all($w1, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

You should execute [preg_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) to know what has failed.

Comment: Place ini_set("pcre.jit", "0"); at the top, like in the code I wrote. It works for me on my computer.

Comment: @SławomirKudła the `pcre.jit` setting was introduced in PHP 7. What PHP version are you using?