# Simple regex seems to cause infinite loop in PHP

Tags: php, regex

The following 2 lines are my code:

```
$rank_content = file_get_contents('https://www.championsofregnum.com/index.php?l=1&ref=gmg&sec=42&world=2');
$tmp_ = preg_replace("/.+width=.16.> /Uis", "", $rank_content, 1);
```

The second line above causes an infinite loop. 
In contrary, the following alternatives DO work:

```
$tmp_ = preg_replace("/.+width=.16.> /Ui", "", $rank_content, 1);
$tmp_ = preg_replace("/[^§]+width=.16.> /Uis", "", $rank_content, 1);
```

But sadly, they do not give me what I want - both alternatives do not include line breaks within `$rank_content`.

Also, if I replaced the `file_get_contents` function with something like

```
$rank_content = "asdfas\nasdfasdfaswidth=m16m> teststring";
```

There are no problems either, although `\n` represents a line break, too, doesn’t it?!

So do I understand it right that RegEx has problems in noticing a String with line breaks in it?

How can I filter a substring of `$rank_content` (which has multiple lines in it) by removing some lines until something like `"width="16" "` appears? (Can be seen in the site's source code)

Comment: No, `\n` represents line breaks only in double quoted string.

Comment: `{1}` is useless in a regex...

Comment: thanks, I edited these two issues

Comment: edited again - s instead of m

Comment: I don't see anything on the linked page that matches `width=.16.>`.  Was that a mistake?

Comment: the source code of the page tells me there are a bunch of phrases like "realm." width="16" src="include...""

Comment: It seems the problem is the LENGTH of the haystack variable $rank_content. Its length is about 90,000, while the maximum allowed length for regex match() is about 30,000.
For those interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268624/php-preg-match-all-limit

I myself am going to solve the problem using another method for reading the contents of a website like HTML Unit.

Comment: What you've got here is an [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You haven't described what you're trying to do and have focussed entirely on the problems of the solution you've chosen to do it. Also, the description is quite misleading - there is no infinite loop, it's very slow, but it'll probably complete if you leave it long enough (it did for me); and it's so slow because of the regex you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up on it: It seems the problem is the LENGTH of the haystack variable $rank_content. Its length is about 90,000, while the maximum allowed length for regex match() is about 30,000, so I guess it is the same for regex replace().
Solving this problem would surely be possible, if somebody is interested: Have a look into this link -> [PHP preg_match_all limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268624/php-preg-match-all-limit)

I myself am going to solve the problem using another method for reading the contents of a website like HTML Unit or maybe retrieving the site line after line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `m` modifier with the `s` modifier. `m` changes the behaviour of `^` and `$`, whereas `s` changes the behaviour of `.`

That said, you should not be parsing HTML with regex. Seriously. [Bad things happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674).

Comment: yes, sorry, s was what I also used in my code. Edited it, problem remains.

Comment: Everyone always links to that post, but never the one right under it.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/485418

Comment: why shouldn't I use regular expressions in order to retrieve some values from a website? Are there better ways to do so?

Comment: edit. I'll have a look at HTMLUnit library.
Does not solve the problem though.