# Catastrophical backtracing because group match is too long

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have created a regular expression pattern that allows me to extract inline styles from any HTML string: https://regex101.com/r/YBdbxS/4 - *to better understand the context, I have created a custom WordPress plugin that extracts inline styles from the current page and puts it into an own file*.

To make the regular expression work again, just remove one `#myid { color: green; }` in the snippet above and it works as expected.

The regular expression worked really well, but now I get a `catastrophical backtracing` error cause the inline style is too long (the WordPress theme I use is using a very long inline style so I am not able to touch the inline style itself; e.g. split it into multiple styles).

#### Temporary solution

I have found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269231/5506547) for this by setting [`pcre.backtrack_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php) to a value like

```php
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "23001337");
```

But this seems to be bad practice.

Is there any alternative e.g. anchor the pattern, so it does not backtrace again and again from the first found match in the `(.*?)` group?

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to use a DOM parser to parse (X)HTML. Do not use regex. You may play with `<style([^>]*)>(.*?)<\/style>`, or with `<style([^>]*)>([^<]*(?:<(?!\/style>)[^<]*)*)<\/style>`, but regex is not meant to parse arbitrary HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Wiktor, the answer is to use a [negative look ahead `?!`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804791/5506547) with a non-capturing group `?:`.

```
<style([^>]*)>([^<]*(?:<(?!\/style>)[^<]*)*)<\/style>
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|       |  *1
                                            ^^^^^^^^^  *2
```

1. Capture all the content before `</style>`. Use the same content as your "closing" pattern of `*2`
2. Your "closing" pattern